# I use limit in GridView but show all record

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
 $Property = Property::find()->limit(1)->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
```

**I use this query with GridView but show all record**

When I use this query

```
$Property = Property::find()->limit(1)->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->all();
```

show error
The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.

Comment: show your related controller/action  please..

Comment: The code you posted where is placed .. model? controller? view? ..

Comment: query in  controller

Comment: edit your questio post an show me  the code for this action .. please

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentatio here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#active-data-provider

> Any existing limit and offset clauses will be overwritten by the
>   pagination request from end users (through the pagination
>   configuration).

Maybe try something like this:

```
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => $Property ,
      'pagination'=>[ 
          'limit'=>1
      ] 
 ]);
```

Read also detailed about pagination:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-pagination.html

And if you only want to display 1 row from a table, maybe you should check DetailView instead of GridView.